# Puxar uma Função Javascript de uma Tag img do HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu estou iniciando meus estudos em `HTML`, `CSS` e `Javascript` e estou com uma dificuldade, estou fazendo um projetinho para meu portifólio uma página de Login porém eu não consigo puxar uma função de JS de uma tag img, eu colo `onclick="Nomedafunção()"` porém não puxa para o JS:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <link rel= "icon" href="Imagens/Favicon.png"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/estilo-loginpage.css">
    <script language="javascript" src="_javacsript/cadastro-loginpage.js"></script>
</head>
    
<body>
    <section id="loginarea">
        <h2>Login Area</h2>
        <input type="text" name="user" id="username" size="40" maxlength="20" placeholder="User name"/>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="40" maxlength="20" placeholder="Password"/>
        <img id="olho" width="20px" src="imagens/Olho Fechado.png" alt="Visualizar Senha" onclick="olhoclick()">
        <input id="botao" type="image" name="enviar" src="Imagens/Submit-Button 2.png" onclick="cadastrar()"/>
    </section>

    <footer id="rodape">
        <p id="copy"> Copyright 2022 - By Rafael Barbosa</p>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```js
function cadastrar() {
    window.alert("Parabêns! Seu Login foi Efetuado!")
}

const passwordInput = document.getElementById("password")
const olho = document.getElementById("olho")

function olhoclick() {
    let inputTypeIsPassword = passwordInput.type == "password"

    if (inputTypeIsPassword) {
        showpassword()
    } else {
        hidepassword()
    }
}

function showpassword() {
    passwordInput.setAttribute("type","text")
    olho.setAttribute("src" , "Olho Aberto.png")
}
function hidepassword() {
    passwordInput.setAttribute("type","password")
    olho.setAttribute("src" , "Olho Fechado.png")
}
```

Comment: Você precisa indicar qual função não está sendo "puxada" e também o código HTML da imagem que "puxa" essa função.

Comment: Olá Rafael, o problema pode ser porque, ai criar a constante "passwordInput" o documento html pode ainda ter sido todo renderizado, o que significa que o variável não aponta para elemento algum. Pode resolver isso colocando o seu código dentro do "document ready" (pesquise isso), ou pode criar a variável dentro da função "olhoclick"

Answer (score -2):

Provavelmente o problema que está acontecendo é que o nome da sua imagem tem espaço, caminhos com espaço não são muito bem vindos, então tente renomear a imagem para olho_aberto.png e olho_fechado.png

Uma dica:
Quando colocar o arquivo JavaScript no seu HTML, prefira colocar no final da sua tag `<body></body>`, dessa forma, você garante que suas funções sejam executadas após o carregamento do HTML. Como as funções que você declarou são eventos, por enquanto não teve esse problema, mas pode ter dependendo da forma que esse seu projeto evolua.

Exemplo:

```
<body>
  <section id="loginarea">
    <h2>Login Area</h2>
    <input type="text" name="user" id="username" size="40" maxlength="20" placeholder="User name" />
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="40" maxlength="20" placeholder="Password" />
    <img id="olho" width="20px" src="imagens/Olho Fechado.png" alt="Visualizar Senha" onclick="olhoclick()">
    <input id="botao" type="image" name="enviar" src="Imagens/Submit-Button 2.png" onclick="cadastrar()" />
  </section>

  <footer id="rodape">
    <p id="copy"> Copyright 2022 - By Rafael Barbosa</p>
  </footer>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

Atualmente a maioria dos navegadores possuem a "Ferramenta do desenvolvedor" que te ajuda a analisar erros nas páginas.
Procure no menu uma opção conforme descrito acima ou tente apertar ( +  + i) juntos;
Dentro desta ferramenta existe uma aba de "Console" que mostrará muitas informações de execução para você.

No seu caso especifico abra o navegador, abra a ferramenta de desenvolver e recarregue a página com a ferramenta aberta e você conseguirá ver os erros de javascript que estão ocorrendo ao fazer o carregamento da página.

Se fosse opinar sobre o problema eu acredito que a resposta do @Ricardo Pontual faz bastante sentido.